# Why pthread_mutex_lock is not marked as async-signal safe?

Tags: linux, unix, pthreads, signals, posix

You see, `sem_post` is marked as async-signal safe. But why `pthread_mutex_lock` is not marked as async-signal safe, while the following program give you the illusion that it is actually async-signal safe?

```
void handle(int arg){
    printf("I wake up!\n");
}
int main()
{
    signal(SIGHUP, handle);
    pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    printf("gonna be blocked\n");

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return 0;
}
```

`kill -hup $pid` will have it print out something. But the lock is still not acquired and program is blocked(I mean, it does not finish), which give me the impression that it is asynchronous signal safe.

You can consult Advanced unix programming environment book, or `man sigaction` to get async-signal safe function list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But why pthread_mutex_lock is not marked as async-signal safe

Because it isn't.

> while the following program give you the illusion that it is actually async-signal safe?

Your program has *nothing* to do with async signal safety. Any conclusion about async signal safety your derived from this test program is plain wrong.

Async signal safety is about being able to call the function *from* an async signal handler.

To see that `pthread_mutex_lock` isn't async signal safe, write a program with 3 threads: one doing `pthread_mutex_lock` and `pthread_mutex_unlock` in a tight loop, one doing the same on the same mutex *from a signal handler*, and a third one that sends an unending stream of `SIGHUP`s to the process.

If `pthread_mutex_lock` were async signal safe, this program would run forever.

But I expect that what you would observe is that this program will either crash or deadlock after a while.

Even if it doesn't, that *still* wouldn't mean that `pthread_mutex_lock` is safe, only that you haven't yet proved that it is *unsafe*.